# Greatest-n-per-group in a one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I'm currently stuck with this (probably) simple query, in which I want to output the newest N TickTimes for each CurrencyID(The newest records added to the table). For only the table "Ticker" I can make this, but in the output I also want to display the MarketName, which is located in the "Currency" table.

```
Currency
+------------+--------------+------------------+------------+----------+--------------+------------+
| CurrencyID | CurrencyName | CurrencyNameLong | MarketName | IsActive | MinTradeSize | TxFee      |
+------------+--------------+------------------+------------+----------+--------------+------------+

Ticker
+----------+------------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
| TickerID | CurrencyID | TickTime            | Bid        | Ask        | Last       | Volume        |
+----------+------------+---------------------+------------+------------+------------+---------------+
```

A possible output will look something like this. (Except I want to return maybe 100 of the last TickTime for each CurrencyID)

```
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
| CurrencyID | MarketName | TickTime            | Last       | Volume        |
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
|          1 | BTC-LTC    | 2017-08-29 16:40:00 | 0.01169000 | 2499.55344592 |
|          1 | BTC-LTC    | 2017-08-29 17:40:04 | 0.01169000 | 2502.10724529 |
|          2 | BTC-VTC    | 2017-08-29 16:40:01 | 0.00021742 | 2791.78613576 |
|          2 | BTC-VTC    | 2017-08-29 17:40:05 | 0.00021742 | 2791.78612635 |
|          3 | BTC-DASH   | 2017-08-29 16:40:02 | 0.07104060 | 660.88002045  |
|          3 | BTC-DASH   | 2017-08-29 17:40:05 | 0.07104090 | 660.87899945  |
|          4 | BTC-XMR    | 2017-08-29 16:40:02 | 0.02178855 | 3681.62291540 |
|          4 | BTC-XMR    | 2017-08-29 17:40:06 | 0.02189143 | 3682.28908088 |
|          5 | BTC-CANN   | 2017-08-29 16:40:03 | 0.00001154 | 1449.06053986 |
|          5 | BTC-CANN   | 2017-08-29 17:40:06 | 0.00001145 | 1447.45006154 |
...
...
|         20 | BTC-BCC    | 2017-08-29 16:40:10 | 0.14265409 | 5196.39621496 |
|         20 | BTC-BCC    | 2017-08-29 17:40:14 | 0.14220000 | 5196.84118604 |
+------------+------------+---------------------+------------+---------------+
```

**EDIT**
I managed to come up with a query that suits my need. Probably not the most efficient one, but the table is not too big...

```
select c.CurrencyID, c.MarketName, t.TickTime, t.Last, t.Volume
from (select t.*,
         (@rn := if(@v = CurrencyID, @rn + 1,
                    if(@v := CurrencyID, 1, 1)
                   )
         ) as rn
  from Ticker t cross join
       (select @v := -1, @rn := 0) params
  order by CurrencyID, TickTime desc
 ) as t
INNER JOIN Currency c 
    on c.CurrencyID=t.CurrencyID
where
    rn <= 3;
```

Comment: adding the market name is the easy part.  You said you already have the query for just ticker already?  What is your existing query so far?  In general it will be something like: 
select ticks.CurrencyId, MarketName, ticks.etc
from (existing ticker select)ticks
inner join Currency curr on ticks.CurrencyId=curr.CurrencyId

Comment: I updated the question with the answer. I came up with a query that gives me the correct output

Comment: You should post that as an answer so that it can help others. It doesn't do much good when posted as part of the question.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think about that. Done it now. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I managed to come up with a query that suits my need. Probably not the most efficient one, but the table is not too big...

```
select c.CurrencyID, c.MarketName, t.TickTime, t.Last, t.Volume
from (select t.*,
         (@rn := if(@v = CurrencyID, @rn + 1,
                    if(@v := CurrencyID, 1, 1)
                   )
         ) as rn
  from Ticker t cross join
       (select @v := -1, @rn := 0) params
  order by CurrencyID, TickTime desc
 ) as t
INNER JOIN Currency c 
    on c.CurrencyID=t.CurrencyID
where
    rn <= 3;
```